# Como Mostrar un GIF mientras carga mi Pagina HTML

Tags: php, html

lo que pasa es que tengo una pagina de html, en la cual estoy cargando informacion(en graficas-highcharts) que traigo desde mi mysql, lo cual distribuyo en un tabla() , pero resulta que como es bastante informacion la pagina esta cargandopor unos segundos, y se muestra de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero mi consulta seria si es que se puede mostrar un gif mientras carga la pagina,  y ya cuando termine de cargar me salgan las graficas que solicito.
osea el gif tiene que salir en toda la pantalla mientras carga la pagina...  como se podria hacer eso, ya que mis graficas no reciben valores, para poder hacer un if con php y poder poner el gif. habra un codigo que si dé?

Comment: Para poder lograr eso, se me ocurre que utilices Ajax, para que cuando se haga la petición al servidor cargues el gift y en el success, es decir cuando ya te regresa la información ocultes ese GIF.